# Filtering out formatting tags from JSoup selectors

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

[JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) here. I have the following HTML I'm trying to parse:

```
<html><head>
<title>My Soup Materials</title>
<!--mstheme--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../_themes/ice/ice1011.css"><meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="ice 1011, default">
</head>
<body><center><table width="92%"><tbody>
<tr>
<td><h2>My Soup Materials</h2>

<table width="100%%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Origin:</b> Belgium</td>
<td align="left"><b>Count:</b> 2 foos</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Supplier:</b> </td>
<td align="left"><b>Must Burninate:</b> Yes</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Type:</b> Fizzbuzz</td>
<td align="left"><b>Add Afterwards:</b> No</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<b><u>Notes</b></u><br>Drink more ovaltine</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</center></body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately its actually slightly malformed (missing some closing tags, opening and closing tags on `<b>` and `<u>` are out of order, etc.) but I'm hoping JSoup can handle that. I don't have control over the HTML.

I have the following Java model/POJO:

```
@Data // lombok; adds ctors, getters, setters, etc.
public class Material {
  private String name;
  private String origin;
  private String count;
  private String supplier;
  private Boolean burninate;
  private String type;
  private Boolean addAfterwards;
}
```

I am trying to get JSoup to parse this HTML and provide a `Material` instance from that parsing.

To grab the data inside the `<table>` I'm pretty close:

```
Material material = new Material();

Elements rows = document.select("table").select("tr");
for (Element row : rows) {

    // row 1: origin & count
    Elements cols = row.select("td");
    for (Element col : cols) {
        material.setOrigin(???);
        material.setCount(???);
    }

}
```

So I'm able to get each `<tr>`, and for each `<tr>` get all of its `<td>` cols. But where I'm hung up is:

```
<td align="left"><b>Origin:</b> Belgium</td>
```

So the `col.text()` for the first `<td>` would be `<b>Origin:</b> Belgium`. **How do I tell JSoup that I only want the "Belgium"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `tdNode.ownText()`. There's also simply `text()`, but [as the docs state](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text()) this combines all text nodes of the node *and all its children* and normalizes them. In other words, `tdNode.text()` gives you the string `"Origin: Belgium"`. `tdNode.ownText()` gives you just `"Belgium"` and `tdNode.child(0).ownText()` gets you just `"Origin:"`.

You can also use `wholeText()`, which is non-normalized, but I think you want the normalization here (that primarily involves getting rid of whitespace).